# To retrieve ECU software number form tune file

Tags: php, file, bin

Is there anyway to retrieve ECU software number from tune file using php programming languages.

Example of the ECU software number: SW upg.: 3FAL2000

Any clue will be appreciated from ECU file Expert

I have tried using specific pattern to retrieve software number from ECU tune file using specific pattern

```
$softwareNumberPatterns = array(
    '/SW\s*:\s*([0-9A-Z-]+)/i',           // Pattern for "SW:" followed by alphanumeric characters and dashes
    '/SW upg\.\s*:\s*([0-9A-Z]+)/i',      // Pattern for "SW upg.:" followed by alphanumeric characters
    '/Software\s*Upgrade\s*:\s*([0-9A-Z-]+)/i',  // Pattern for "Software Upgrade:" followed by alphanumeric characters and dashes
    '/Software\s*Version\s*:\s*([0-9A-Z-]+)/i',  // Pattern for "Software Version:" followed by alphanumeric characters and dashes
);
```

Comment: Skipping PHP for now, do you know for a fact that this file contains that data? I’m asking because I know absolutely nothing about this file format. If it _does_ contain it, then yes PHP or any other programming language can get the data out.

Comment: as the ecu file is written in hex or binary, i used a desktop software to read it and i get software number from the file.

my main concern i know a website which is php based, and when i upload a ecu file then they search software number from the file and they suggest a similar software number file to buy, i want this feature to my car tuning website